# swift firebase one to many example?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been created 2 tables below. I want to select table **friends** and I want to display **name** from table user ? anyone can help me for example in swift please thank you.

Table user

```
 id
 name
 email
```

Table friends

```
 id
 user_id
 friend_id
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) _"Please give me code"_ isn't the way this site works. Show your own efforts and explain your problem. Please look at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Your realtime database should look something like this.

```
{
    "users": {
        "1": {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john@example.com"
        },
        "2": {
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "email": "jane@example.com"
        }
    },
    "user-friends": {
        "1": {
            "2": true
        },
        "2": {
            "1": true
        }
    }
}
```

To get the friends of John, we observe the path `/user-friends/1`

```
let uid = 1 // the uid of the user we want the friends of
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child('user-friends/\(uid)')

ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, block: { snapshot in

    let uid = snapshot.key // the uid of a user who is John's friend
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child('users/\(uid)')

    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, block: { snapshot in
        if let json = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            print(json["name"])
        }
    })
})
```